# StackOverflowError in Twitter example

Tags: android, twitter

I am using this simple code to connect with Twitter. First line works fine but when the second line gets executed it starts creating buffer.

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter(userName, password);
twitter.setStatus("This is my first Tweet from Android -  AndroidPeople.com");
```

My logcat shows only this following line repeated until this throws a `StackOverflowError`.

> 05-09 13:28:40.936: INFO/global(309): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.` is a warning, not an error, so the problem is most likely that so much buffering is going on - possibly the request is failing and the Twitter API you are using does not handle this well (ie retries ad infinitum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking the Twitter API, I read that this Mechanism for Login into Twitter is not supported after June 30, 2010. So this code doesn't work any more. I have to use the OAuth concept for Twitter Login. For this OAuth I need customer key and customer password and a callback url under the link [Twitter New Apps](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new).
This StackOverflow Error comes when the my program tries to connect and  connect twitter for login and it is rejected everytime, so buffer fills up and overflows.